# Why don't private blockchain networks that do not charge for transactions charge a fee when processing ethereum/ proprietary token on the network?

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-fees, mining-theory, mining-profitability, mining-reward

I ask this questions because there seems to be 2 flavors of blockchain: 1. Public think bitcoin and ethereum. 2. Private hyperledger, SAP Leonaro, etc. The public network charges for transactions to incentive nodes to process the transaction. The private network does not charge for transactions which is why it is popular with businesses. Why is there no network that can do both? For example eosio | Blockchain software architecture  is trying to make it cheaper to process transactions which I assume is meant to appeal to businesses and consumers. Why cannot a private blockchain such as Hyperledger Sawtooth/ Fabric which are private be free for businesses to use because businesses validate transactions but also accept a token which has value and when a consumer users the token to purchase an item from a business in the network either charge a fee for validating the transaction or do not charge for it.

Comment: I'm trying to describe is businesses are always going to prefer useing something that is free. For example, it would be too costly to have to pay a transaction fee for a high volume manufacturing company when they wanted to add data to the blockchain. At the same time, businesses want to accept tokens for purchasing their items. Why can't businesses use blockchain/ Hyperledger Fabric for the private networks internal use but have a Fabric token to use when businesses on the private network purchase items from eachother or consumers purchase products from the business?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Sawtooth and other private blockchains (or enterprise blockchains) restrict the set of nodes allowed in the blockchain network. There is no need for cash payment, because it is an internal operation in an organization or consortium of organizations.  One of the main values of enterprise blockchains is to escape the high fees and overhead and delay from third-party arbitrators of transactions, whether it be stock, securities, money, or goods.